# Is there any way to know how many pokemon you have?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

Is there any way to know how many Pokemon you currently have either on your team or in your PC? Is there any way to know which species of Pokemon you currently own? For example, if you have a Charmander and then he evolves to Charmeleon, Charmander doesn't count because you have a Charmeleon, not a Charmander.

I'm looking for both in-game solutions as well as those making use of third-party applications (like an Android application).

Comment: Assuming you don't mess with the Pokémon boxes, meaning you don't have lonely Pokémon in random boxes: Every box can hold 30 Pokémon, totalling 930 Pokémon for all 31 boxes, plus 6 Pokémon currently in your Team. I'm sure counting the number of full boxes * 30 then adding the rest is easier than counting every single Pokémon one by one. Other than that, I am not aware of any automated method of counting the number of Pokémon you currently have. There is most definitely no Android/iOS app for that.

Comment: @Nolonar It's not a bad idea, but I want an app that lets you know, when a Pokémon appears, if you have caught this Pokémon or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a website/webapp that provides a Pokedex style Checklist.

Each Pokemon has a check-box next to it which you can tick to mark if you currently have it or not.

If it evolves, you can simply untick it if you don't have a duplicate.

I'm not sure how the site stores the information so I assume it's locally which means the moment you clear your cache/history etc, you may lose your checklist and unfortunately it's not up-to-date with X and Y Pokemon yet.

The website can be found [here](http://www.pokechecklist.com/pokedex). I don't think there is an iOS or Android app though.
Good luck.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. But I prefer an offline and mobile application, because I always have my smartphone when I'm playing with my Nintendo 2DS. I think I'm going to use this _pokechecklist_, but I'm a programmer, so maybe I will make one Pokémon checklist.

Comment: Awesome. Be sure to let us know if you develop one; I'd be interested in using it too. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Ok! :). I will contact with Nintendo to ask for permission.